# Pandas: changing the data after saving and loading

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, which contains column `user_pseudo_id` and it looks like

```
user_pseudo_id
2041513012.1676969234
2041513191.1677359234
2041513765.1677359510
```

And it's a string type.
Then I try to save it and load it again. So the problem is that I get the different values in this column.

I get

```
user_pseudo_id
2041513012.1676967
2041513191.1677360
2041513765.1677360
```

For writing and loading I use usual code

```
df.to_csv(path_to_data, index=False)
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_data)
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `dtype={'user_pseudo_id': object}` as `read_csv` parameter

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `read_csv` is automatically converting the data to floats (because it looks like one). You can explicitily define the type of a column using the `dtype` parameter, like so:

`df = pd.read_csv(path_to_data, dtype={'user_pseudo_id': str})`

More info in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)